# Circle Invalid-data Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet with many dependant dropdowns that are liable to having invalid data if the initial drop down is altered. I would like a simple auto-macro that would automatically run the "circle invalid data" command every time a cell change within a specified range (D8:T800) is detected.

It sounds fairly straightforward but I am not sure how to do this.

Question - as this macro will run every single time a cell is amended would this macro slow down the worksheet?

EDIT: 
Also: as this might be slow,is there a way we can run this command over a selected range?

Your thoughts thanks.

Comment: It doesn't sound at all straightforward. I don't understand what your layout looks like and what exactly you are trying to achieve.
Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask, especially "Do your homework" and "Be specific".

Comment: You cannot run the Circle Invalid Data routine on a subrange of a Worksheet. If you wish to perform a validation on only a specific  subrange it is probably best to either specify and implement your own validation formatting, which can applied through VBA, or  separate the data onto a different worksheet.

You can use the `.Validation` property of a Range to apply/remove the formatting

Comment: Also, your question is still very non-specific and vague. Please include an example of the data and an indication of the size of the dataset you are working with. Also post an example of the code you have so far

Comment: Great question. Not sure if has been updated since ExternalUse's comment but it makes perfect sense to me and I found this question search for precisely what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D8:T800")) Is Nothing Then
        Me.CircleInvalid
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that `CircleInvalid` applies to the whole sheet, so while this code only triggers when a cell inside `D8:T800` changes, *all* invalid cells on the sheet will be circled

Comment: Yes, this is the version we have gone with! Works well!

Answer (score 1):

Try placing this code inside your Worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

' Check target range has changed
If (Not Intersect(Target, Range("D8:T800")) Is Nothing) Then
    ' Prevent recusrive looping
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ' Refresh validation circles
    Target.Worksheet.CircleInvalid

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```

Note that this will NOT work if the values in those cells change due to a calculation from outside the specified range.

Also, the CircleInvalid method applies to the whole worksheet.

You could try editing the code in the conditional to 'do something' if the Target is validated — this would result in you changing the format of invalid cells instead of having the red circles around them.

```
**PSEUDO-CODE**
For each cell in Target.Range
    cell.colour = bright red
Next cell
```

Comment: I see, thanks will keep this in mind.      Recording a macro seems to imply that:     ActiveSheet.CircleInvalid      is the command

Comment: I'm trying to work out how to fire the Circle Invalid Data routine at the minute... good question : )

Comment: Did it work okay for you? It works within the fairly loose specification of the question. Please accept if this answer proved to be an answer to your question.

Comment: This slows done the sheet HUGELY lol.  Is there a way we can limit this to just Rows containing "SupplierConfig" in the supplier column? I.E a slightly more dynamic range?

Comment: I would normally move this to chat but you do not have enough reputation. Can you update your initial question to specify the issue more clearly. I added some text explaining why the CircleInvalid method can only work on the whole worksheet.

Comment: Yes the CircleInvalid is forced to be across entire sheet, but the range here can be tweaked to be dynamic which is useful in our case.